# Changing font styles of lightdm-gtk-greeter

Tags: unity, themes, fonts, lightdm, gtk

I can change my font using the following option in `lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`:

```
font-name = ...
```

But I'm not sure how to change the size or weight. I tried putting the following CSS in my GTK theme:

```css
#login_window .entry {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

But it's not really working. Exactly which classes should I target to change the font style of the login window?